# Comment rendre en français "handle" dans "handling polynomials"

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

> Octave has a special way of *handling* polynomials.

(GNU Octave est un logiciel libre de calcul numérique comparable à MATLAB.)

Je me demande si la traduction serait :

> Octave a une façon particulière de *gérer* les polynômes.

ou bien

> Octave a une façon particulière de *manipuler* les polynômes.

Je crois que le verbe *gérer* peut rendre dans ce contexte le sens du verbe *handle*. Cela est correct ?

Comment: *gérer* is more like have something under one's control, decide how something will function. I suggest *traiter*.

Comment: `handling` in this case is pretty much the same as saying `working with` so `gérer` sounds closer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first choice

> Octave a une façon particulière de gérer les polynômes.

Mean you manage polynomials (like you create or delete polynomials).

And

> Octave a une façon particulière de manipuler les polynômes.

Mean you transform polynomials.

I don't know what Octave do but I think

> Octave a une façon particulière de gérer les polynômes.

is better

Comment: I think I prefer "traiter" suggested by @Luke Sawczak; Also, "s'occuper de" or "travailler avec" would do it.

Comment: Like you want, like I said I don't know what is Octave (maybe because I'm native in french or is it a software). "traiter", "s'occuper de" or "travailler avec" work too. :)

Comment: In computer science we often translate 'handling' or 'manage' by 'gérer' and processing by 'traiter'. Gérer seems a lot better here for me.

Answer (score 3):

En plus de *gérer*, *manipuler* (qui rend le mieux l'étymologie anglaise), et *traiter*, je propose: **appréhender**. Mais ça convient mieux si Octave est une personne et pas un logiciel.

Comment: +1. On pourrait aussi penser à ***aborder***, voire *attaquer les* ou *s’attaquer aux* polynômes.

Comment: Je ne trouve pas appréhender approprié, désolé.

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence with the closest meaning of:

> Octave has a special way of *handling* polynomials.

Is the following:

> Octave a une façon particulière de ***traiter*** les polynômes.

However adding more context would definitely solve this translation issue.